# What can I do to dry out my marshmallows?

Tags: food-science, gelling-agents, marshmallow

The recipe that I used did not call for cornstarch or corn syrup. The result is that they are slightly wet. Can I do anything to dry them up, such as dusting them with corn flour?

I did dredge them in a mixture of confectioners sugar and corn flour; it helped a little, but I think I will find a recipe that has corn starch in it for next time!

Comment: I think you need to tell us which ingredient you **did** use instead of the ingredient you didn't use.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think I've ever seen a marshmallow recipe without corn syrup, except maybe for methocel marshmallows.  But assuming these are standard gelatin marshmallows, you can dredge them in confectioner's sugar and that will make them easier to work with.

Don't "dust" them, actually *dredge* them, otherwise you'll just end up with globs of wet sugar attached to the exterior.  This might happen anyway if your marshmallows are particularly watery, so you might need to dredge them a few times.

Also, don't cover them; it's important to let any moisture evaporate.  Gelatin is pretty stable as a gelling agent, but fresh marshmallows are still prone to syneresis, and if you leave them in an enclosed container, the condensation will cause more problems.

If worse comes to worst and the sugar doesn't help, just leave them out in the open for a longer period.  The water will continue to evaporate over time and eventually they will reach the consistency you want - although they might shrink a fair amount before then.

Comment: Recipes marshmallows
Special Occasions
Soft & Squishy Marshmallows
Makes about 40 marshmallows

Ingredients
60 ml ( ¼ cup) Cold Water
37 ml (2 ½ tbsp) Gelatine
185 ml ( ¾ cup) Boiling Water
500 ml (2 cups) Huletts White Sugar
1 Egg White
Pinch of Salt
3 ml ( ½ tsp) Vanilla Essence

Comment: The recipe calls to dust the marshmallows in corn flour, which I did but it did not help.

Comment: @Yurisa: Please edit your question by clicking the "edit" link under the tags; the recipe you tried is important information which belongs in the question rather than a comment.

Comment: Separately, @Yurisa, as I pointed out, dusting in anything will not help, you need to dredge, and I would use confectioner's sugar rather than corn starch. Corn starch isn't going to have very good flavour and confectioner's sugar already has corn starch in it.